# Wild Card Search Strings in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement wild cards in Java.

Here is the code I have

```
public class Assign {

    public boolean compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        char [] s3 = s1.toCharArray();
        char [] s4 = s2.toCharArray();
        int i,j;

        int k = 0;
        for(i=0;i<s3.length;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<s4.length;j++)
            {
                if(s3[i] == s4[j])
                {

                    if(s4[j] == '*')
                    {
                        i++;

                        if(s3[i] == s4[s4.length-1])
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Assign a = new Assign();
        boolean r = a.compare("a hello b", "a * b");
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

There will be two parameters to be passed to the function. One is a string and the other one is a regular expression.

Example cases are:

1) If string passed is "a hello b" and the regular expression is "a * b" then the function should return TRUE because in the place of * any number of characters can exist.

2) If string passed is "a X b" and the regular expression is "a ? b" then the return value should be TRUE because if there is a ? in regular expression then there should be only one character between a and b.

Like this it shall work for all cases. I think the logic I thought is fine but I ma having a trouble in the coding part.

I dont want to import Pattern and Matcher. Without them I have to complete this.

Kindly, anyone help me on this.

Thanking you

Comment: Why do not you use the support for regular expressions built into Java?

Comment: Your regex is wrong. It should be "a.*b"

Comment: Besides that your regex is wrong, take a look at this first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html

Comment: @Petr an assignment maybe?

Comment: I don't think he wants *true* regex. He just wants `*` to mean a word and `?` to mean a character. Is this correct?

Comment: Not exactly. its not just a word. I converted the string to a character array and I am comparing the two arrays. If there is a * in the regular expression, that means the first string should be parsed until a character in it matches the ending character of the regular expression. There can be any number of characters.

For ? in the regular expression there should be only one character in the string

Comment: I should not use the original Finite Automata principles here

Answer (score 0):

If you see a '?' then skip a character.  If you see a '*' then call your search function recursively on the remaining input until you find a match.

Comment: yeah exactly. that is what I want. Can you please help me with the code?